# The current path, login/accounts/login/, didn’t match any of these

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm trying to make a login application, however whenever I try to log in using my template it gives this error.''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import login
urlpatterns = [
    path('', login),
    path('login/', login, name="login"),    
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from CRUDfuncionario.models import Funcionario
# Create your views here.
def login(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request,'login.html')
    else:
        idFuncionario = request.POST.get("idFuncionario") 
        senha = request.POST.get("senha")
        user = Funcionario.objects.filter(idFuncionario=idFuncionario, senha=senha)
        if user:
            return HttpResponse('autenticado')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Email ou senha invalidos')
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action= "{% url 'login' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" placeholder="Identificação" name="idFuncionario">
        <br>

        <input type="text" placeholder="Senha" name="senha">
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class LoginConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'login'
```

settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-2$2#kr-+3(*k46w+*+r-ij5@=bhhzuee$o57%@3rgfofo%ek&('

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


# Application definition
# Aplicações existentes, somente lembrando que ao criar um aplicação nova pelo terminal, para que ela exista
# e seja detectada no sistema é necessário registra-la na sua aplicação.
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_plotly_dash.apps.DjangoPlotlyDashConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'KoiApp.apps.KoiappConfig',
    'CRUDfuncionario',
    'cpf_field',
    'login',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'koiProject.urls'
```

Eu não sei mais o que fazer sobre isto, somente sinto que é algo relacionado ao próprio django, espero que possam me ajudar.

Comment: Stack Overflow is English only.